# Regular expressions: How to filter for two things at once

Tags: python, regex

I want a regular expression that will return all words in a list that contain only consonants and no special characters.

The following Python code works:

```
import re

words = ["xkcd", "word", "xml-"]
consonants_only = [x for x in words
                      if (re.search("^[^aeiou]+$", x)
                        and re.search("^[a-z]+$", x))]

print consonants_only
```

This accurately returns ['xkcd']

My question is: can this be done nicely with a single regular expression? What I'm looking for is a general way to filter for [^aeiou] AND [a-z] at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `look-around assertion` to combine them:

```
import re
input = ["xkcd", "word", "xml-"]
output = [i for i in input if re.match(r'(?=^[^aeiou]+$)^[a-z]+$', i)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know all of the consonants beforehand:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ["xkcd", "word", "xml-"]
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+$')
>>> [word for word in words if pattern.match(word)]
['xkcd']
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check for absence of vowels using `[^aeiou]`?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik in this case there could be other characters, like in the `xml-` string - as OP said this shouldn't match. If you want to go with negative assertion - you may find @kev's answer correct.

Comment: This way is better since it only needs to parse the string once and the pattern will fail at the first forbidden character.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write the 21 consonants between the brackets:

```
[bcd...xyz]+
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the regexp search for only consonants? Something like this should work:

```
import re

words = ["xkcd", "word", "xml-"]
consonants_only = [x for x in words if re.search("^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+$", x)]

print consonants_only
```

That will be more efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, use a Positive Lookahead and instead of search use the match method.

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['xkcd', 'word', 'xml-']
>>> [x for x in words if re.match(r'(?=[a-z]+$)[^aeiou]+$', x)]
['xkcd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Through negative lookahead assertion,

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ["xkcd", "word", "xml-"]
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])+$')
>>> [word for word in words if pattern.match(word)]
['xkcd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's better to create a reusable function so you can use it map to check all your variables.

```
def consOrvows(words):
vowels = []
cons = []
for word in words:
    if re.match(r'[aeiou]',word):
        vowels.append(word)
    elif re.match(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]',word):
        cons.append(word)
return vowels,cons

list(map(consOrvows,words))
```